# HIFLD Railroads DB contains coordinates that don't make sense

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, osgeo4w, mysql-spatial

I downloaded the [HIFLD Railroads DB](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/2a9677db741d4a78bd221586fe9a61f5_0) and imported it into MySQL with [OSGeo4W](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15453939/569976). I then do this query and the coordinates I get just don't make sense:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJson(SHAPE)
FROM railroads
WHERE OGR_FID = 123751;
```

Here's what I get back:

```
{
   "type":"LineString",
   "coordinates":[
      [
         -10791447.5365,
         3527298.6227
      ],
...
   ]
}
```

That's not a GPS coordinate. idk what that is.

When I use OSGeo4W with another DB ([TIGER County DB](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/COUNTY/)) I get coordinates that *do* make sense. The query I use with that:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJson(SHAPE)
FROM county_shapes
WHERE OGR_FID = 1637;
```

The result:

```
{
   "type":"Polygon",
   "coordinates":[
      [
         [
            -97.997996,
            30.720209
         ],
...
      ]
   ]
}
```

Those coordinates make sense so using OSGeo4W *can* work but it just isn't for the HIFLD Railroads DB.

Any ideas?

Comment: The railroads dataset is projected in Web Mercator (EPSG:3857). The coordinates that you see are Web Mercator X,Y coordinates in meters. You could transform the data into EPSG:4326 in order to get WGS84 degrees.